# Web API, DI and object lifetime via nested containers?

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, asp.net-web-api

OK, I wired up StructureMap to my Web Api application (plenty of samples how to do this here on StackOverflow and elsewhere on the Internet). My understanding of object lifetime maintenance in Web Api is that it's done via nested containers.

For the whole idea of object lifetime maintenance via nested containers to work, Raven's session object would have to be created in child container as a transient singleton. Right now I have `IDocumentStore` defined in in parent container and scoped as singleton. `IDocumentSession` is also defined in parent container but scoped as HttpContext. When request comes in, `BeginScope()` is called, nested container is created but `IDocumentSession` object in it is inherited from the parent instead of being created.

I don't understand how this is supposed to work. If object is not created in child container as a transient singleton but is inherited from the parent instead then it will go back to the parent when nested container is disposed. This then defeats the whole idea. If on the other hand session is to be created in nested container as a transient singleton then how this can be accomplished? How can I verify the correctness of such setup?

Comment: Since you defined the `IDocumentSession` as Per Web Request, why do you need child containers anyway? And what is a "transient singleton" for lifestyle exactly? This is new to me.

Comment: @Steven, that's the source of confusion for me. If I set `IDocumentSession` as Per Web Request then why the need for nested containers in the first place (since the parent manages the lifecycle). You can either create instances in child container and then dispose the whole thing when done or let the parent manage it for you. 'Transient singletons' = define object as transient in parent container (i.e. For<ISome>().Use<Some>()) then in a child container it's created as singleton thus 'transient singleton' - poor choice of words.

Comment: "Transient Singleton", I would rather call is "child container scoped" :-)

Answer (score 1):

> If I set IDocumentSession as Per Web Request then why the need for
>   nested containers in the first place?

There is no need for nested containers in that scenario.

The need for nested containers by itself in general is even doubtful. Even [the designer of Castle Windsor](http://kozmic.pl/) (a container that supports child containers) [is considering to remove support for child containers](http://kozmic.pl/2010/06/01/castle-windsor-and-child-containers/) in the next version of Castle Windsor all together.

Comment: I agree, there wouldn't be. But, then, every implementation of DI in context of Web Api uses nested containers. Look [here](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/per-request-dependencies-in-aspnet-web-api-using-structuremap) or at StructureMap.MVC4 nuget source. However, nested container approach might be StructureMap specific as this is IoC container of my choice and I was looking for solutions, which used it. +1 for your help, thanks.